# OpenSuse - network problems

Tags: opensuse, networkmanager, filezilla

1: When trying to connect to cloud server Filezilla complains.

```
Error:  expected key exchange group packet from server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I can ssh to server from command line. Opensuse 13.1 -had no problems.

2: Using Network setting manager (Not using wicked! ), I cant set 802.11 n WLAN.. likely netwotk setting.

3: Firewall has no interfaces selected. Likely network problem.

```
Status: Connecting to ...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "xxx@222.222.222.222" 22
Error:  expected key exchange group packet from server
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to 222.222.222.222...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "122@1222.222.222.222" 22
Error:  expected key exchange group packet from server
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect to the server with Filezilla?

Comment: How old is that Filezilla?

Comment: Filezilla is 3.7.3, Using Xfce,  also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed filezilla from repo -- This solved the filezilla errors.

Answer (score 2):

From your explanations and details, assuming the errors are relevant for the actual problem, I am fairly confident that the issue is an inconsistency between FZ and SSH server.

Apparently the group for the key exchange that the server is supposed to reply with was not received by FZ. It is more secure to allow the SFTP server to manage this but in your case, it would be interesting to see what happens if you specify the same fixed group on both sides (assuming FZ has this configuration option).

You could also increase the verbosity of the SFTP/SSH server, try again and give the output here.

Your ssh session could have worked simply because the client could have attempted to use a specific group without expecting it from the server.